# Can anyone explain ASP.NET Web Pages Life cycle ? (Razor syntax)

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

I want to know the life cycle of ASP.NET Web Pages using razor syntax.

From questions asked on life cycle of ASP.NET MVC Controller on Stack Overflow, answers suggest that its is explained at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx . So I am not asking the same question.

For a pure ASP.NET Web pages project (and not MVC), I want to know the sequence of events that takes place when a .CSHTML file is requested by the browser.

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense, the page lifecycle applies to aspx web forms (non MVC) applications. Im pretty certain that you cannot use razor outside of MVC and it does not have a 'lifecycle' as you are talking about.

Comment: for asp.net (aspx) life cycle try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @NicholasKing Razor was originally developed for the ASP.NET Web Pages framework: http://www.asp.net/web-pages. It was borrowed later by the MVC team as a new View engine.

Comment: @MikeBrind I did not know that, but looking at that page on ASP.NET Web pages looks like an MVC pattern without the microsoft MVC stuff.

Comment: @NicholasKing There is no hint of the MVC pattern in Web Pages. It takes a page-centric approach like classic ASP or PHP.

Comment: @MikeBrind i looked at the Twitter code sample(http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/learning-the-basics-of-using-the-twitter-api-in-aspnet-web-pages-with-razor-syntax) and it has a poco Model class, razor views and action methods such as public static List<TwitterEntry> TwitterSearch(string value) looks like an MVC pattern to me. But i bow down to your greater knowledge. Its just my impressions from viewing the link you sent.

Comment: @NicholasKing That's just a basic class with some helper methods. There is no Action, no Model, no Controller. It's slightly more advanced than most Web Pages samples, but it is definitely not MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Web Pages project, C# classes that inherit from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage` are generated from the Razor file when the first request to the application is made. The class has one method: Execute, which contains your server-side code and a number of WriteLiteral calls that output the HTML. Each class is named after the original .cshtml file eg `Default.cshtml` becomes

```
public class _Page_Default_cshtml : WebPage
```

The classes are compiled to a dll. Requests are routed to the appropriate class.

Web Pages is not an event-driven development model like Web Forms, so there are no particular events as such that you can hook into like PreRender or Page_Load etc.

Comment: Would appreciate pointers to any links which might have any more details on this. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: What kind of detail are you looking for?

Comment: I'm guessing this is likely a Bad Idea(TM) but how about (skipping controllers and) overriding WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy, putting what would be PreRender code in there (using your own dynamic ViewBag), and then invoking base.ExecutePageHierarchy?